# Convert different varchar dates to date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having some troubles with converting varchar types to date types.
In SQL-server 2008 I'm having a table with different types of dates in type VARCHAR.
For example:

```
DDMMYYYY (05032013)<br/>
MMDDYYYY (03052013)<br/>
YYYYMMDD (20130305)<br/>
...
```

I have to convert these different string types to type "date" using a SQL-query.
Any suggestions how I can do this?
These are my records:

```
TYPE    ||    FORMAT  
____________________
DDMMYYYY||05032013  
MMDDYYYY||03052013  
YYYYMMDD||20130305
```

Comment: How will Identify whether date given is in **DDMMYYYY** or **MMDDYYYY** or **YYYYMMDD**. if you can answer this, We will make sure you will get the answer. **:)** between Good Question +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`SELECT case 
when type='DDMMYYYY' then convert(date,STUFF(STUFF('05032013',3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'),105)
when type='MMDDYYYY' then cast(substring('03052013',5,4)+'-'+substring('03052013',0,3)+'-'+substring('03052013',3,2) as date)
when type='YYYYMMDD' then cast(STUFF(STUFF('20130305',5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') as date)
end`

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify every row which date format is, you can convert them to date type. Otherwise i don't think that it will be completely correct. For example you can't implement logic for the following record - (03052013) can be 2013-05-03 or 2013-03-05.

Comment: In my table I have a column which indentifies the format, and another column with the dates in that format. And it is the date which has to be converted to type "DATE".

Comment: Give us the DataStructure of the tables and some Records. Also give us meaning of Codes.